# I want to scroll the page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to scroll the page iI used following code but I need to move scrollbar manually up to 1/4th then it get scroll automatically what is the reason behind this, any new code suggestion.

```
Actions dragger = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement draggablePartOfScrollbar = driver.findElement(By.className("mCSB_dragger_bar"));
    int numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown = 1000;
    dragger.moveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(10,numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown).release().perform();
    dragger.moveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(10,numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally use JavascriptExecutor for this purpose.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight," + "document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
```